# Cloning Self Referencing Classes/ Linked Objects in Java

Tags: java, binary-tree

Consider the following class which represents a node of Binary Tree.

```
public class BinaryTreeNode {
  private int key;
  private BinaryTreeNode left;
  private BinaryTreeNode right;

  public BinaryTreeNode(int key) {
    this.key = key;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }

  public BinaryTreeNode(int key, BinaryTreeNode left, BinaryTreeNode right) {
    this.key = key;
    this.setLeft(left);;
    this.setRight(right);
  }

}
```

Now in Constructor `BinaryTreeNode(int key, BinaryTreeNode left, BinaryTreeNode right)`, as far as I know, setting the left/right node directly is a bad idea, and should not be done. A possible way could be to Create a copy using `clone()` and set it as `left`/ `right`. But it will be a shallow copy, and it will create problems as `BinaryTreeNode` also has the non-primitive field which is `BinaryTreeNode` itself. So now I am stuck on how to create a copy-constructor in such a scenario?
Any lead will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Think it depends on how you are going to use this structure. Possible ways:

1. Leave as is, if single-threaded app will fill the structure and than use it.
2. Make fields final (so `BinaryTreeNode` becomes immutable), and change setters in order to return new instance with new right/left (so no duplication and no concurrent modifications), should be ok for usage in multithreaded env.
3. Clone structures? Probably ok for some cases. You need to implement clone itself and assign cloned copy (in constructor and in setter), but I would say that you need again to mark fields final and with such simple structure you will get case 2 with additional overhead on cloning.

Comment: Yes, except that in a binary tree, you can't really make the fields final if you want to add and remove nodes.

Comment: You can. If your `setLeft`/`setRight` returns new object with updated left/right node. Do you really need to transform current object or new object is ok (which will re-use and share safely not-touched nodes)? With mutable nodes and defensive copies you will get much more overhead on create/utilize. Having structure you described I do not see any profit to transform with clone vs immutability with new object creation on `setLeft`/`setRight`. I would say that it will be slower and error-prone. Or I miss anything?..